# Mocking third party dependencies in the provider tests using pact

Tags: jestjs, mocking, pact

Currently I have setup a provider test, that actually calls my provider and returns a response, which is then compared in the pact broker to the expected response body. However by calling my provider, it is running internal code that makes an axious call to another external endpoint to get a response, which it then does some mapping and returns a response back to the pact broker. Is there a way I can mock/stub this third party response, so it is not actually hitting the third part end point.

```
//Inside provider test
it('matches the consumer contract', async () => {
    await new Verifier(opts).verifyProvider();
}, 30000);
```

//Call to third party which then uses the response

```
const response = await axiosInstance.post(url, input.body, {
    headers: {
        Authorization: `${input.token}`,
    },
});
```

Can I just mock out axious in jest?

Comment: Why not simply mock your internal provider to simply return what you are trying to test?

Comment: @StevenScott How would I do this so that it only mocks the provider, during to the contract pact test?

Comment: Instead of providing the service, provide a mock that simply returns the result you expect.    https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-functions#mock-return-values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Currently I have setup a provider test, that actually calls my provider and returns a response, which is then compared in the pact broker to the expected response body.

In a consumer test, the Pact Broker is not part of the test at all. In fact, the Pact Broker doesn't do any testing at all - it is the point of collaboration for teams to share contracts, communicate work in progress and more.

> However by calling my provider, it is running internal code that makes an axious call to another external endpoint to get a response, which it then does some mapping and returns a response back to the pact broker.

Again, no Pact Broker involved here. It is the Pact framework that is doing the communication to your code (on the consumer side, it acts as the fake provider, and vice versa for a provider test).

> Is there a way I can mock/stub this third-party response, so it is not actually hitting the third part endpoint.

As suggested in the comments above, you should [stub out this endpoint](https://docs.pact.io/provider#stub-calls-to-downstream-systems).

You should treat Pact as a unit testing tool. Strictly speaking, it isn't, but that is the mindset you need to bring to a Pact test. If you can't stub out dependencies in the test, that tells me one of the following is likely going on:

1. You are trying to test it "from the outside" i.e. as a black box type test. This is not recommended. See this video on [testing scope](https://docs.pact.io/getting_started/testing-scope) for more.
2. Your code is not very modular, making it hard to unit test. You should refactor your code to make it more testable